# Compiled Python code doesn't run in terminal

Tags: python, compilation

I have a python script that I compiled into a Ubuntu Executable. However when I run the executable nothing happens I'm using pyinstaller, and I know its working because another project (That uses tkinter) I did executes in the tkinter window, I guess the question I have is how do I get the compiled python code to run in the terminal instead of a tkinter window.

I compiled both projects the normal way with pyinstaller, but the does that used a tkinter window runs just fine, but the code that should print to the terminal (after asking for the location of a file via `askopenfilename`) doesn't run at all.

Comment: Did you try to comment the **askopenfilename** and just print something like **hello world** to the console ? It's a bit hard to help more with only a few infos.

Comment: I also did a hello world script and compiled it with the same results